# Analysing number of errors with ANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova

I have the following dataset

```
library(car)
library(ez)

dat <- structure(list(numbers = c(4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 
3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 8, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 6, 8, 8, 
8, 6, 8, 8, 8, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 8, 6, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 9, 7, 9, 7, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 9, 7, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 9), condition = c("controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", "controltrue", 
"controltrue"), key = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", 
"g", "g", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", 
"g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", 
"g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", 
"g", "g", "g", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "g", "g", "g", "g", 
"g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", 
"g"), accuracy = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), RTs = c(0.433440075489, 
0.584262928925, 0.900921091321, 0.650958113838, 0.384471354773, 
0.484353395877, 0.367676318623, 0.80092431698, 0.600955694448, 
0.417601027526, 0.416974943597, 0.334586234763, 0.351031572558, 
0.450530192116, 0.916829419206, 0.333611185662, 0.517596335616, 
0.384416737361, 0.684295259416, 0.750973949209, 0.767682843842, 
0.450949169695, 0.466901118401, 0.334349070676, 0.450331150103, 
0.650875638006, 0.767181023373, 0.516833524685, 0.317576028174, 
0.434385433211, 1.43416476424, 0.984174514655, 0.684317253064, 
0.484326637001, 0.550981133827, 0.551001294749, 0.500949389767, 
1.33413536614, 0.384293939918, 0.416949284263, 0.384314100724, 
0.484288514825, 0.450997555861, 0.550951809157, 0.617581746541, 
0.650942718377, 0.767599268118, 0.53431109502, 0.451014050981, 
1.11751613207, 1.08416322456, 0.667607259005, 0.567603520118, 
0.567682696972, 0.634281843435, 0.334355668398, 0.334310948383, 
0.417710262351, 0.784255377483, 0.550962439273, 0.750906869303, 
0.434287562035, 0.417775876354, 0.384364685975, 0.434299658053, 
0.484298411757, 0.483843877792, 0.666952216734, 0.417631818564, 
0.434350610012, 0.350977688329, 0.501701937057, 0.434329716023, 
0.401814764133, 0.517609531758, 0.3343586009, 0.500969551038, 
0.46698616026, 0.484318206087, 0.6168882153, 0.416916294023, 
0.401016396936, 0.634216595774, 0.400972409756, 0.81760022114, 
0.417864584015, 0.501075852895, 0.484331035754, 0.467665028758, 
0.867562685395, 0.43438396696, 0.467593549751, 0.517631158698, 
0.367689514998, 0.450537156698, 0.716814610176, 0.467556160642, 
0.400933554512, 0.417823895928, 0.900883702328, 0.834234703798, 
0.36768218386, 0.40100246761, 0.450967864366, 0.550976368599, 
0.45093743992, 0.484216302633, 0.500258058077, 0.61761400383, 
1.11749157286, 0.501043595839, 0.484376122709, 0.500976148527, 
0.351031939033, 0.517575074919, 0.784278837498, 0.867508801108, 
1.01678257284, 0.51763152529, 0.5509294488, 0.617823675973, 0.767636657227, 
0.450994256651, 0.734270920046, 0.734351563035, 0.800978201441, 
0.517633358482, 0.450958700385, 0.400935020763, 0.484300611075, 
0.417713195086, 0.584306549281, 0.367692081258, 0.384340859484, 
0.600864421227, 0.367676685564, 0.351042935858, 0.317690394819, 
0.384351123241, 0.450992057449, 0.484310508356, 0.816703982418, 
0.916879637865, 0.516891807551, 0.417754616123, 0.501040663105, 
0.451032012235, 0.384372383589, 0.550228953362, 0.567485487787, 
0.484277151525, 0.500982380006), participant = c(5, 6, 10, 17, 
21, 22, 27, 29, 29, 30, 32, 35, 38, 5, 10, 18, 18, 20, 20, 20, 
22, 35, 37, 38, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 
14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 17, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 23, 
23, 24, 25, 25, 27, 28, 31, 31, 36, 37, 37, 37, 38, 1, 1, 11, 
15, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 27, 28, 32, 33, 34, 37, 37, 1, 9, 11, 
11, 19, 19, 22, 24, 26, 27, 34, 37, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 10, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 19, 19, 20, 22, 23, 31, 37, 38, 38, 2, 5, 
7, 12, 17, 20, 22, 26, 26, 29, 29, 35, 35, 35, 36, 37, 37, 38, 
4, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 10, 12, 12, 16, 18, 20, 21, 23, 24, 24, 24, 
29), hand = c("left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "right", 
"right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", 
"right", "right", "right", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "right", "right", "right", 
"right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", 
"right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", 
"right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", 
"right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", 
"right", "right", "right", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "right", "right", "right", 
"right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", 
"right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", 
"right"), parity = c("even", "even", "even", "even", "even", 
"even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", 
"even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", 
"even", "even", "even", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "even", "even", 
"even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", 
"even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", 
"even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", 
"even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", "even", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd"
), magnitude = c("small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", "small", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", 
"large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large", "large"
)), row.names = c(NA, 152L), class = "data.frame")
```

My aim is to perform a 2x2 factorial ANOVA. My two factors will be **hand** and **parity** and my dependent variable is **accuracy** where 1 = correct and 0 = error. I am focusing on errors for my ANOVA so I have filtered so only errors (0's) remain.

Does anybody know how to perform an ANOVA on differences in the number of errors for my factors? My first attempt produced an error:

```
ezANOVA(dat, dv = accuracy, wid = participant, within = .(parity, hand), type = 3, detailed = TRUE, return_aov = TRUE)

Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within = within,  : 
  One or more cells is missing data. Try using ezDesign() to check your data.
```

I think this is because all of the accuracy values are 0 whereas I want analyse the *number* of 0's (number of errors) for my factorial ANOVA. Hence I then tried to average across each condition and re-ran the ANOVA however I run into more problems.

I'm averaging across subjects so I lose my within subjects variable (thus I cannot use the ezANOVA function). I then try and use the aov() and Anova() functions but generate a new error:

```
dat <- dat %>%
  dplyr::group_by(parity, hand) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(acc_num = n())

result <- aov(acc_num ~ parity * hand, data = dat)
Anova(result, type = 3)

Error in Anova.lm(mod, ...) : residual df = 0
```

Does anybody have any idea how I would analyse this data using an ANOVA in R? Any help is most appreciated!

Comment: With a 0/1 type of outcome ANOVA doesn’t seem appropriate. Consider a logistic multiple regression instead.

Comment: hi @EdM is this still possible when my predictors (hand and parity) would be factor variable types?

Comment: No, a dichotomous dependent variable means you cannot use standard ANOVA as the assumptions are strongly and obviously violated. It really is not difficult to do logistic regression. Countless tutorials can be found.

Comment: Also, I don't understand "I am focusing on errors for my ANOVA so I have filtered so only errors (0's) remain". If you do this filtering, there is nothing to analyze statistically.

Comment: The logistic regression ultimately gets to the probability of making an error, which is usually of most interest in a situation like this. To get probabilities you need to know about both correct cases and errors. So the filtering down to error cases is throwing away a lot of important information.

Comment: hey @EdM I have done some reading and have not implemented a multiple logistic regression rather than an ANOVA. Thanks for you guidance!

Comment: and thank you @Roland